# SMR-weighted model to estimate ATT

Tags: propensity-scores

I am using SMR weights in a logistic regression model.  Everyone in the exposed group gets a weight of 1, and everyone in the unexposed group gets a weight of propensity score/(1-propensity score).  Because there are so many more unexposed, the weights in the unexposed group are very small.  If I divide all the weights in the unexposed group by the mean weight in that group (so that the mean is 1), am I still estimating the average treatment effect on the treated (ATT)? (I get the same answer using these 2 sets of weights if I treat all the observations as independent, but very different answers with the 2 sets of weights if I account for the clustering in the data - any advice on how to know which weights should be used?)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "account for the clustering in the data" and provide some example code and output?